# Filtering parameters in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, parameters, cakephp-2.6

In Rails, [we can](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) specify the allowed parameters to be used in the controller when saving data. So, with `params` being the submitted data, I can do this:

```
params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
```

Which will ensure that the `:person` key is present and will filter out anything that is not a person's `:name` or `:age`.

Is there any way in CakePHP to accomplish this?

EDIT: I know I can write PHP, I want to know if there's a Cake component / plugin that already does this.

Comment: :name and :age is also array keys? :name = Pinto, :age = 30 ?

Comment: @Salines in Rails `params` is a hash and you can nest other hashes or arrays, so in the example `params[:person][:name]` would be the name, etc.

Comment: Search plugins / components here: https://packagist.org/search/?q=cakephp%20filter

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the `fieldList` param in `Model::save()`, which allows you to whitelist fields during a save. See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array

Answer (score 2):

Something in this PHP way:

```
// submited data
$this->request->data['Person'] = array(
   'name' => 'Salines',
   'age' => '41',
   'job' => 'Web Developer'
);

// check if isset and filter out anything that is not a person's name or age

if(isset($this->request->data['Person']))
{
    $permit = array('name' => '','age' => '');
    $this->request->data['Person'] = array_intersect_key($this->request->data['Person'],$permit);
}

//and return $this->request->data like 
array(
   'Person' => array(
       'name' => 'Salines',
       'age' => '41'
   )
);
```

Comment: thanks @Salines, I edited my question to make it clear that I'm looking for a Cake-provided solution (if there is one)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a Cake-provided solution (if there is one)

Well, define "cake-provided", you mean by the framework itself? No, the core doesn't have this functionality but there are two plugins.

- For Cake3: [Plum Search](https://github.com/skie/plum_search)
- For Cake2 & 3: [CakeDC Search](https://github.com/cakedc/search)

For Cake3 I would go for Plum-Search, it is written by the same person as the initial code of the other plugin but a complete rewrite and makes a better use of Cake3.

Next time you ask name your exact Cake version.

Both plugins implement the PRG pattern but don't explicitly allow or deny query parameters. They'll only grab the parameters you specified in your filter declaration and turn them into the request. Validate and save to exclude unwanted fields.

Answer (score -1):

Make a url link like this

```
echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'hello','par1'=>23,'par2'=>'sud'));
```

In hello function in users controller

```
pr($this->params->named['par1']); 
pr($this->params->named['par2']);
```